# Ignite ui, Where I can find info about the latest version

Tags: ignite-ui

I have Googled about the lastest Version of ignite ui. The only info I got is, it is "2018.2". Is there any place where I can find info about Patches stuff. e.g. I have now Infragistic.Web.Mvc.dll Version 5.18.1.40. Is it the latest one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core portion of the product, which is on GitHub, follows the same versioning, as the full version. You can check all the available versions, as well as the latest one here:

https://github.com/IgniteUI/ignite-ui/releases

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.infragistics.com/support/service-releases) you can see our Service Release Schedule and all upcoming and current releases for all IG products.